# Isotope Grid layout use empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a grid (3x3) which is 300px and each grid field is 100px wide.

Its very simple to explain if you'll have a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pEZtj/) here.
Onloads layout isotope its working well, but if you click for example on the `li` element #2 the grid is going to be resorted, but without using its space correctly.

Why is next to `li` 3 and empty area? `li` 4 will fit in there!
Thought isotope will handle this? How to get this?

Thanks for your help!
frgtv10

http://jsfiddle.net/pEZtj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your fit order function.  When you click on 2 it sets it's order to 2.5 (index of 1 + 1.5), which is still less than the order of 4 (index of 3).  The same thing applies to 3 which has an order of 2.

To fix this you need a more complex order function.  Assuming you only need this to work for four elements the following code should work.

```
if(index == 0) { //element 1 should appear first
      order = 0;
}
else if ( $item.hasClass('large') && index % 3 == 1 ) {
      order = index + 2.5;
}
else if ( $item.hasClass('large') && index % 3 == 2 ) {
      order = index + 1.5;
}  
else {
      order = index;
}
```

EDIT: To make the code a little prettier and support any size rows you can make the sort function look like this:

```
int columns = 3;
if(index % columns == 0) { //element 1 should appear first
      order = index;
}
else if ( $item.hasClass('large')) {
      order = index + columns - (index % columns) + .5;
} 
else {
      order = index;
}
```

Comment: can you give a hint what to do with having 6 `li` items? to make it dynamic?

Comment: do you want to have it appear with 5 elements in the row above the one large element or do you want two rows of three with the one large element.

The code I posted should work for any amount of rows of three.  To make it dynamic I think doing order = index + rowSize - index % rowSize + .5 should work

Comment: the grid is always like 3 wide and 3 high. is there no dynamic way?

Comment: The edit I posted should be dynamic.  Just set the columns to 3 and make sure you're container is wide/tall enough

Comment: this will work as expected! thank you very much. do you have an idea how to get this working with jquery sortable? to sort the objects in another order?